# Correct way to get Facebook App Access Token from iOS App to post an app_link

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an iOS app with Facebook integration. I've set up the native up on Facebook as a Facebook app, so I have an app id and I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK to login to enable posting etc.

Ultimately I need to be able to make a post to the Facebook app page or feed from the ios app. The post will display a story with a user added message ( which is optional ), and will also contain an app link with some additional parameters which define a profile for parsing when the app link opens the app.

There will also be a fall back url if a user selected the post in the browser on the desktop which will take them to the Facebook app page or the company page.

I've tried to do this using open graph objects and types, I'm able to make the post to the current users wall but I've noticed the data in the object explorer tool on Facebook is linked to that user. After further reading it appears that I need to make the post using an app token, then the Facebook app is the owner of the data and I can post this to the app feed or page.

My first question, is this a correct assumption that the app token will enable for page or feed posting?

If this is correct I'm trying to find the right way to get an app token. From the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) it warns from storing the app secret in the client and recommends this request be made server side:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &amp;client_secret={app-secret}
    &amp;grant_type=client_credentials
```

I'm assuming I would need to add code to our own server which inturn would make the request to Facebook and return a valid app token, is this correct?

If this is correct is there any easy cloud based solution for me to set up this basic request as I don't have much server side coding knowledge, or is there a way I can achieve this all from within the app without embedding the app secret?

Comment: Do you need to create them on demand, or are you just looking to create a few urls? If the latter, then you can use this tool to create them: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/applinkshost

Comment: Your app secret should never be exposed in client-side code. If you want to built this, you should do it server-side.

Comment: Thx for feedback, looks like server side is way to go. I need to make app links on demand. I've tried the applinks host but was unsure it provided functionality required. I need users of the app to post a message to the Facebook app page with an image, an app link with params which define a profile created by the app. E.g. 'myapp://version=1&0=00FF00&1=FFFF00&2=CFFFF00'. When another user clicks link in Facebook it opens the app, loads and displays the profile with the colour parameters passed in. Be interested to know if this is beyond the scope of app links in Facebook or a valid use case?